# IntelliJ doesn't recognize Scala project

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I just cloned a scala project and opened it with IntelliJ.
It looks that IntelliJ doesn't recognize this project as a scala project.

For example, in Project Structure, language level is set to a Java version number:
[image]

build.sbt file looks with errors:
[image]

and whenever I click on class name in the code I get an error from IntelliJ: "Cannot find declaration to go to".

Do you know how to resolve it?

Comment: Did you import it as an SBT project?

Answer (score 0):

do you have  scala plugin installed? Try invalidating the caches/ restart.
For more info - https://www.javahelps.com/2018/12/setup-scala-on-intellij-idea.html

Answer (score 0):

That's something also confused me really,
sometime it could be recognized automatic, but sometime it's not work.
finally, i found a way to figure it out.
just follow the step as below, it will make sure the project be imported as sbt.

1. Clone repo.
2. Open IntelliJ
3. File -> New -> Project from existing sources
4. Choose Import as sbt
5. Fill in import box
6. Done

[For Reference](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000003504-IntelliJ-not-recognizing-other-SBT-project-in-multi-project-build)